# Is there any predefined Date Grok Pattern for [Thu Dec 13 16:05:57 IST 2018]

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have below log:

**[Thu Dec 13 16:05:57 IST 2018]** Tomcat Start Called

I have tried below date patter but not get success:

`\[%{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{TZ} %{YEAR}\]
%{DATESTAMP_OTHER:timestamp}
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}
%{HTTPDERROR_DATE:timestamp}`

Is there any predefined date grok pattern to parse above string?

Answer (score 2):

`DATESTAMP_OTHER` has all the components in the right order, but, as you've discovered, doesn't match the sample input you've provided.

The cause is that `TZ` (used in `DATESTAMP_OTHER`) does not match `IST`:

```
TZ (?:[APMCE][SD]T|UTC)
```

They've been discussing [the issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/issues/172) for over two years.

For your local uses, you could add 'I' the pattern:

```
TZ (?:[APMCEI][SD]T|UTC)
```

which would also allow for IDT, or add it explicitly:

TZ (?:[APMCE][SD]T|UTC|IST)